# Windows Authentication Not working in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an ASP .net web application that uses windows authentication. The page displays logged in persons user name (Controller.User.Identity.Name), and has `<authentication mode="Windows" />` in web.config. The page works fine in the current server, and my local machine. But when i deployed it to beanstalk server the page doesn't prompt for credentials.

Below are the steps i have done so far.
I figured out that i have to enable windows authentication in the EBS IIS server.
Added a AWS Elastic Beanstalk configuration file (.ebxtensions) with below command

```
commands:
 01-install-windows-auth:
command: powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned "Add-WindowsFeature Web-Security,Web-Windows-Auth"
ignoreErrors: true
waitAfterCompletion: 5
 02-enable-iis-windows-auth:
command: powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned "Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter '/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication' -Name Enabled -Value True -PSPath 'IIS:\' -Location 'Default Web Site'"
ignoreErrors: true
waitAfterCompletion: 5
```

The Log File from my EB environment:

```
2017-12-15 10:27:02,152 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils - Updating file (Default Web Site/Auth.aspx).
2017-12-15 10:27:02,152 INFO 1 DeploymentLog - Updating file (Default Web Site/Auth.aspx).
2017-12-15 10:27:02,152 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils - Updating file (Default Web Site/bin\AuthAWS.dll).
2017-12-15 10:27:02,152 INFO 1 DeploymentLog - Updating file (Default Web Site/bin\AuthAWS.dll).
2017-12-15 10:27:02,152 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils - Updating file (Default Web Site/bin\AuthAWS.pdb).
2017-12-15 10:27:02,152 INFO 1 DeploymentLog - Updating file (Default Web Site/bin\AuthAWS.pdb).
2017-12-15 10:27:02,168 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils - Updating file (Default Web Site/Web.config).
2017-12-15 10:27:02,168 INFO 1 DeploymentLog - Updating file (Default Web Site/Web.config).
2017-12-15 10:27:02,168 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils - Adding ACL's for path (Default Web Site/)
2017-12-15 10:27:02,168 INFO 1 DeploymentLog - Adding ACL's for path (Default Web Site/)
2017-12-15 10:27:02,183 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils - Adding ACL's for path (Default Web Site/)
2017-12-15 10:27:02,183 INFO 1 DeploymentLog - Adding ACL's for path (Default Web Site/)

 2017-12-15 13:51:00,910 [INFO] Command 01-install-windows-auth succeeded
 2017-12-15 13:51:00,910 [INFO] Waiting 5 seconds for reboot
 2017-12-15 13:51:06,487 [INFO] Command 02-enable-iis-windows-auth succeeded
 2017-12-15 13:51:06,487 [INFO] Waiting 5 seconds for reboot
 2017-12-15 13:51:11,519 [INFO] Running configSet Hook-PreAppDeploy
 2017-12-15 13:51:11,519 [INFO] Running config Hook-PreAppDeploy
 2017-12-15 13:51:13,410 [INFO] Command hooks succeeded
 2017-12-15 13:51:13,440 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
 2017-12-15 13:51:13,440 [INFO] Running configSet Hook-EnactAppDeploy
 2017-12-15 13:51:13,457 [INFO] Running config Hook-EnactAppDeploy
 2017-12-15 13:51:17,237 [INFO] Command hooks succeeded
 2017-12-15 13:51:17,253 [INFO] Running configSet Hook-PostAppDeploy
 2017-12-15 13:51:17,269 [INFO] Running config Hook-PostAppDeploy
 2017-12-15 13:51:21,769 [INFO] Command hooks succeeded
 2017-12-15 13:51:21,783 [INFO] ConfigSets completed
```

I guess the authentication was successfully added to the added. I restarted my EBS instance and nothing happened. It still doesnt ask for any authentication on log in.

I have searched on google and it all points to the creation of .ebextensions to configure IIS on the EBS environment. Am i missing something? i just need to enable windows authentication on my application. Any Ideas?

Comment: You say it does not prompt for authentication. But you don't say **what it does**. Does it show the protected content? Does it show a 401 error? Something else?

Comment: It enters the page without authentication with No error

Comment: for testing i included only only a single line of code - to returns logged in persons name. and yes, it shows the page contents, without the login person name.

Comment: Do you have `[Authorize]` attributes on your MVC controllers and/or actions that require authentication?

Comment: yes, i use this to invoke authentication- System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;. and to clarify it works as expected on a server on premise, but the issue is only with the EBS instance