# Is there any way to configure/enable windows authentication in IIS server in Elastic beanstalk using aws cdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, windows-authentication, aws-cdk

I have AWS CDK code which creates EB infrastructure for my asp.net application.
This cdk script created Elastic beanstalk environment with windows IIS server.
I am able to deploy me application to EB environment but now the problem is my application uses windows authentication and I want to change my CDK code so that it will enable windows authentication on IIS server inside EB.

Can we do that using CDK or can we run batch file in EB server using AWS CDK.

Comment: Are you deploying your application from CDK? If so, you can include [ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-windows-ec2.html) in the source bundle to enable windows authentication. An example command is shown in this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/47834257/2995727

Comment: @LaurensKnoll  yes I am using aws CDK and the link you are referring it looks like using AWS CLI correct me if I am wrong . I want to do it using CDK app (using typescript as language)